# Разные метки имеют одинаковое описание

Tags: обсуждение, метки, описание-метки

Я не уверен что я правильно понял, но все-таки решил написать. Есть одна метка `SharedPreferences` с таким описанием:

```
интерфейс андроид API, который дает возможность работы с файлы настроек приложения. 
Приложение хранит простые данные в виде «ключ — значение». 
Но, разработчиками часто используется для хранения небольшого количества данных как альтернатива 
БД или кастомных текстовых файлов.
```

и есть вторая метка `android-shared-preferences` с таким же описанием. Может нужно оставить одну метку? Мне честно говоря немного стремновато задавать такой серьезный вопрос по сайту, но я решил написать, так как хочу помочь в развитии этого ресурса.

Comment: Синонимизируем, как только модератор онлайн будет. Такие вопросы нужно задавать. Спасибо)

Comment: ок, если что буду писать)